# Are there alternative representations of the following integral?

Tags: integration

What are the alternative representations, if any, of the following integral?

$$\int^{-n^{-1/4}}_{-\infty}y \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{n}{2}(y - \theta)^2\right) \space dy + \int^{\infty}_{n^{-1/4}}y \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{n}{2}(y - \theta)^2\right) \space dy$$

Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

As this particular question is about integration only, I felt it was appropriate to post here. For those wishing to know of the broader statistical context in which this integral appears, I have also asked something similar on Cross Validated, but with much more of an emphasis on the statistical angle.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525906/deriving-the-risk-of-the-hodges-le-cam-estimator-under-l-2-squared-error-loss

Comment: Well you can change variables to relate it to the incomplete Gamma function. I am not sure what else you might want to do.

Comment: @Ian. I would like to plot this integral over $\theta \in [-2, 2]$ for different values of $n = 5, 50, 500$. To do so say in Python `scipy.stats`, rather than say symbolic computing software like Mathematica requires that I be able to specify this integral in terms of known, possibly special functions. Please may you show me how that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two integrals of the form

$$I(a,b) = \int_a^b (y-\theta)\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)\:dy + \int_a^b\theta\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)\:dy$$

$$= \int\limits_{\min\left(\frac{n}{2}(a-\theta)^2,\frac{n}{2}(b-\theta)^2\right)}^{\max\left(\frac{n}{2}(a-\theta)^2,\frac{n}{2}(b-\theta)^2\right)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\exp(-t)\:dt + \int\limits_{\min\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(a-\theta),\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(b-\theta)\right)}^{\max\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(a-\theta),\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(b-\theta)\right)}\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-s^2)\:ds$$

both of which have known antiderivatives

$$I(n^{-\frac{1}{4}},\infty) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(n^{-\frac{1}{4}}-\theta)^2\right)+\frac{\theta}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(n^{-\frac{1}{4}}-\theta)\right)$$

$$I(-\infty,-n^{-\frac{1}{4}}) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(n^{-\frac{1}{4}}+\theta)^2\right)+\frac{\theta}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(n^{-\frac{1}{4}}+\theta)\right)$$

which yields the required result.

Comment: Do you know of any undergrad level calculus textbooks or references where I can read up on the specific techniques and $\text{erfc}$ function you’ve used? It would enable me to derive more value from your answer.

Comment: @microhaus any book that teaches u-substitution and has a table of integrals. There are no advanced techniques being used. If you want to learn erfc, look up its definition and learn how to pattern match - it is the most useful skill I have ever picked up.

Comment: It's taken me a bit of time to parse your solution due to my rusty calculus. That coupled with the max-mins in the bounds of integration, and also by the $\text{erfc}$ function, which I've never used in integration before, led me to erroneously infer that something esoteric was going on when it is in fact integration by substitution,  with some 'tricks' motivated by knowledge of anti-derivatives. If I understand correctly, your reaffirmation that the principles are still the same has been incredibly useful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This expression can be written in terms of the integral of $e^{-x^2}$. Let $F_\lambda(t)=\int_{-\infty}^te^{-(\lambda x)^2}dx$ and $F=F_1$ ($F$ is a standard function). Factor out $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}$. We then have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{-n^{-1/4}}y\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)&=\int_{-\infty}^{-n^{-1/4}}(y-\theta)\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)+\int_{-\infty}^{-n^{-1/4}}\theta\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)\\
&=-\frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right)\bigg|_{-\infty}^{-n^{-1/4}}+\theta F_{\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}}(-n^{-1/4}-\theta)\\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(-n^{-1/4}-\theta)^2\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\theta F\left(-\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}(-n^{-1/4}-\theta)\right),
\end{align*}
and you can do essentially the same thing for the second term.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Is there a name for the function $F$? Is it the error function?

Comment: $F$ is basically the error function. The error function is defined as $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^te^{-x^2}dx$, so depending on $t$'s sign, $F(t)$ is half of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$ plus or minus the appropriate error function value.